# How to use a python script in a backend?

Tags: python, php, web-applications, backend

How you can read in the title: How can I use and integrate a Python script in a backend from a web applicaton? The backend use php as programming language and the database MySql.

Comment: The best way is rewrite Python logic in PHP script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a python script from PHP, you can use one of the many PHP functions which do this, for example: [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Depending on what you want, it can be as simple as:

```php
<?php
exec('python script.py');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I have to develop a machine learning application and integrate that later in the backend from this web application.

Comment: @christhebliss then this solution is not fit for you - it is too simpleand will time out. You need to look into proper background scheduling solutions like celery or rabbitmq, where the web application built in php is used to start and monitor tasks, your background scheduler runs the various background processes (including the models in python) and report back on the progress.